# To create a Tree Grid Structure from the JSON input using nestedSortable jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop, nested-sortable

I have the following JSON file:

```
[{
  "Parent 1": [{
    "Child 1.1.1": 1,
    "Child 1.1.2": "W1T1",
    "Child 1.1.3": 1.5,
    "Child 1.1.4": [{
      "Child 1.1.4.1.1": 1,
      "Child 1.1.4.1.2": "W1T1C1",
      "Child 1.1.4.1.3": 0.75
    }, {
      "Child 1.1.4.2.1": 2,
      "Child 1.1.4.2.2": "W1T1C2",
      "Child 1.1.4.2.3": 0.5
    }]
  }, {
    "Child 1.2.1": 2,
    "Child 1.2.2": "W1T2",
    "Child 1.2.3": 3,
    "Child 1.2.4": [{
      "Child 1.2.4.1.1": 1,
      "Child 1.2.4.1.2": "W1T2C1",
      "Child 1.2.4.1.3": 1
    }, {
      "Child 1.2.4.2.1": 2,
      "Child 1.2.4.2.2": "W1T2C2",
      "Child 1.2.4.2.3": 1.5
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "Parent 2": [{
    "Child 2.1.1": 1,
    "Child 2.1.2": "W2T1",
    "Child 2.1.3": 1.5,
    "Child 2.1.4": [{
      "Child 2.1.4.1.1": 1,
      "Child 2.1.4.1.2": "W2T1C1",
      "Child 2.1.4.1.3": 0.75
    }, {
      "Child 2.1.4.2.1": 2,
      "Child 2.1.4.2.2": "W2T1C2",
      "Child 2.1.4.2.3": 0.5
    }]
  }, {
    "Child 2.2.1": 2,
    "Child 2.2.2": "W2T2",
    "Child 2.2.3": 3,
    "Child 2.2.4": [{
      "Child 2.2.4.1.1": 1,
      "Child 2.2.4.1.2": "W2T2C1",
      "Child 2.2.4.2.3": 1
    }, {
      "Child 2.2.4.2.1": 2,
      "Child 2.2.4.2.2": "W2T2C2",
      "Child 2.2.4.2.3": 1.5
    }]
  }]
}]
```

The above **JSON** is a *valid JSON* file (checked using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)). Also, you could see the desired parent-child structure by overwriting my JSON code [here](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/#/)

I want to create a **tree grid** like view using **nested sortable plugin**. This plugin is available [here](http://ilikenwf.github.io/example.html). This shows data in tree view, but the values are hard-coded. I want to replace those values with the values within my **JSON** file. It should identify the parent and child nodes and render appropriately. How do I make all this dynamically rendered ?

Does anyone have a workaround for this ?